# How to layer a partially tranparent UIImageView on top of an UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView with a fixed image. I would like to add a second UIImageView on top, that I intent to rotate. I need to create the top image at runtime. I can't find where to deal with transparency. Is it in the UIImage or in the UIImageView ? So far, I have a black background on the top UIImageView, but I would like to see through these black pixels. Here is the code: ( this is based on from Erica Sadun's [Core iOS 6 Developers Cookbook](https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Cookbook/tree/master/C02%20Controls/07-Touch%20Wheel) ). I would like to add dots on the wheel to add some feedback for the rotation of the control.

```
    float width=200, height=200;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), YES, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    float lineWidth=4;
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,  CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), lineWidth, lineWidth));
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    dots = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView * ivDots = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dots];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheel.png"]];

    [self addSubview:iv];
    [self addSubview:ivDots];
```

Comment: Is the image used in the top image view transparent? i.e. does it have transparency in it somewhere?

Comment: I am creating it at runtime, and I'm expecting it to have a transparent background because I'm filling a rectangle of the same size of the UIImage with [UIColor clearColor]. See line 7 in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify opaque  with `NO` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 0.0);` else there will no alpha channel in the resulting image => it will have black pixels instead of transparent.

Also:

- you dont need to clear the context before drawing, as it is already cleared.
- you dont need to push and pop the context, as you do not nest different contexts.